# Laravel 4 store() method error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've looked around to see if I can find this specific problem, but have been unsuccessful so far.

The problem is pretty simple.  I'm using an artisan-generated UsersController to handle RESTful communication on the /users directory.  GET works just fine, but whenever I POST a form to /users, instead of executing the store() method properly like it should, it throws the MethodNotAllowedHttpException error.  When I made a new handler postNew(), and POST to users/new, it works just fine.  I could just use that, but I would really like to figure out what the problem is so I can use the standard RESTful method.

Additionally, I'm not using Laravel's form generator because I intend to cache every page for speed, and don't want to generate a unique id for every form I send.  I saw on another post that this might be causing problems, but couldn't figure out a way to integrate it into a solution.

```
<form id="signup-form" method="POST" action="users">                         
  <label>First Name:</label>                    
  <input type="text" name="firstName">                  
  <label>Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastName">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up Free!">
</form>
```

That's my code.

Comment: How did you setup your route for this new controller?

Comment: Typed `php artisan controller:make UsersController` in the command line.  The out-of-the-box configuration did not work, and that's what confuses me.

Comment: Are you sure that, you are using the right `HTTP` method to submit the form ?

Comment: I'm updating the post with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`controller:make` will only create a resource controller, it will not define its route(s).

Since you mention that you created a new controller method `postNew()`, and it works when you send a POST request to `users/new`, I will assume that you have created a *RESTful controller* route and **not** a *resource* route.

RESTful controller route (not compatible with `controller:make`):

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

Resource controller route (compatible with `controller:make`):

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

The differences between these two controller types are outlined on the [Controllers docs page](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers): [RESTfull](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) vs. [Resource](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: Brilliant! I had it as Route::controller(...), and not as Route::resource(...).  Changing it to a resource controller fixed the problem immediately.